# I want to Get QUICKBOOKS to read/write to the database of IMS FLEET MAINTENANCE and VICE VERSA, i need help.sql

Tags: sql

Quickbooks is an accounting application and IMS fllet maintenance is a and inventory/maintenance reminder application.
I need to use Quickbooks to access some tables in the db of IMS fleet maintenance and vice versa, if possible all tables, please can someone help me with how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to access all tables in the db. The software is called DoIT and it reads the data from the inventory/maintenance application and automatically moves the info to Quickbooks. This is done without accessing the QODBC read/write driver. You do not have to develop in house some middle-ware.

Answer (score 0):

There are ODBC and ADO.NET drivers for Quickbooks. Some of them claim read/write access. I think Quickbooks ships with a read-only ODBC driver, but I could be wrong. (I use Quickbooks, but I don't use the ODBC driver.) I'm pretty sure the QODBC driver doesn't allow access to every table, but that's a limitation of the Quickbooks SDK.

[Google search results](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=quickbooks+odbc)

[QODBC read/write driver](http://www.qodbc.com/orderupgradeqbes.htm)

[Intuit's ODBC FAQ](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/Articles/INF12836#update)

Answer (score 0):

Over at the [Intuit Developer Network](http://qbsdk.developer.intuit.com/sdk/qb) you can register and download the Quickbooks SDK. It is a full featured SDK that exposes the underlying quickbooks data. There are numerous examples and a vibrant developer network on the site.

Using the Quickbooks SDK you should be able to develop some middleware to move data between Quickbooks and your IMS system.

Comment: It looks like you do not even need to register in order to download the SDK.